# Парсинг всего сайта с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Осваиваю парсинг сайтов, в связи с чем возник вопрос, на который никак не могу найти ответ.

Задача стоит следующая: прошерстить все страницы  сайта, и посчитать, сколько раз там встречается заданное слово. На данный момент я разобрался, как сделать вышесказанное только на одной странице. Как можно организовать автоматический переход со страницы на страницу, чтобы пропарсить полностью весь сайт?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задачу можно разбить на несколько этапов:

1. Получаем содержимое страницы и выполняем нужный анализ.

   ```
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.site.com/").get();
   processDoc(doc);
   ```
2. Находим на текущей странице все ссылки с этим же доменом и добавляем их в очередь, предварительно отфильтровав те ссылки, которые уже были посещены.

   ```
   Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
   for (Element link : links) {
       String absLink = link.attr("abs:href");
       if (absLink.contains("site.com") && notYetVisited(absLink))
           addToQueue(absLink);
   }
   ```
3. Пока очередь еще не пуста, извлекаем очередную ссылку и переходим шагу 1.

Если сайт большой, то необходимо предусмотреть хранение очереди ссылок и списка посещенных ссылок в базе данных. Вот подробный [пример](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/) с решением похожей задачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое, и за пример тоже, сайт как раз таки большущий)