# Java: Работа с сайтом

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, бот

*Не жду готовых решений и конкретных ответов. Интересует направление и возможно источники которые помогут это реализовать.*
*Не минусуйте просто так, я не знаю просто где это узнать (Гугл толком не помог)*

Необходимо реализовать работу бота на java, он должен выполнять некоторые действия на сайте, клики, закрывать окна.(Не для игр и прочего).
Я лично предположил, что необходимо получать html код сайта и его же парсить. Но не понимаю как сделать конкретно действия и в конкретном месте.
Скажите что необходимо для этого? Если скинете ссылки или доки по этой теме, буду благодарен.

Comment: Для этого нужно использовать [Selenium WebDriver](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) (все извесные браузеры поддерживаются).  
Который даст возможность управлять браузером к примеру `Google Chrome` который представляет сам [chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/) для работы с `API` браузера.

Comment: вроде можно было с помощью jsoup https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526116/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jsoup https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20jsoup&lr=10335&clid=2186621

Comment: @And Бота писать на селениуме? Но там нет такого API для создания ботов.

Comment: @RomanC там есть уже готовые вещи которые можно брать и использовать. Я писал очень даже не плохо. Ознакомьтесь сначала с ним, а потом пишите.

Comment: @Tsyklop Уже ознакомилен, форкнул первую версию и далее развивал лично для интеграции своих приложений.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо! Ребята я рад что вы поняли меня, я бы всем вам поставил плюсы. Но нет ещё 15 рейтинга.
Вопрос пока открыт, у  кого есть желание дополняйте (Может помочь кому нибудь в будущем).

Answer (score 0):

Для создания бота рекомендую использовать [Selenium WebDriver](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
Примеры в инете есть, поддержка браузеров тоже.